# Retrieve form input and use it within a string

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to take input values from a form and output the results within a string. I don't want to use a database to do so.

Is this possible? Do I have to run the variables through a function? If so how can I go about it?

I'm new to react so providing pseudo-code could possibly make this more difficult than it needs to be but I will do my best.

```
    <div className="form">
      <form
        name="contact"
        method="POST"
      >
//variable name
        <input name="name" placeholder="Your Name" type="text" />
//variable age
        <input name="age" placeholder="Your Age" type="number" />
//submit
        <button>Send</button>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Based on the form above I expect to be able to somehow fetch the input values in the form after submit and have them display within a string.

Ex: Your name is "name" and your age is "age".

The result would be displayed on the same page if possible.

Thank you in advance for any help provided.

Comment: There's a good document for managing form by React. https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Comment: @zmag Thank you, the documentation is great but I am missing a step. The first codepen shows how to console log the input value which is very close. From there how can I use that same input value and log it within a concatenated string? Specifically this codepen https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/VmmPgp?editors=0010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could write you a bunch of theories, facts, and opinion-based statements.
Instead of that, I've chosen to write down the code. Look at the comments for more insight into the workflow, and if you have any questions, I'll be here to provide help.

**Run the code snippet** and see ti in action.

```js
class FormComponent extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {name: '', age: null, submitted: false}; // Here we're saving our input values

    
  }

// Let's handle the input changes
// This is a great approach, since we don't need to write multiple 'onChange' handlers.
// Depending on what's the current 'name' of the input, we're assigning the currently entered value.
// We're accessing it via the 'e' -event parameter that's automatically passed to us

 handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value});
  }

// This is our onSubmit handler
   handleSubmit = (e) => { // same e parameter
    const { name, age, submitted } = this.state; // here we're doing a bit od es6 destructuring

    // Instead of showing that 'alert' we'll change the 'submitted' part of the state to true. This check is going to be useful when we come to the part where we want to check if the user has clicked the button if YES, this part will be equal to true and we'll show them the output if not, nothing will be shown.

    // alert(`Your name is ${name} and you're ${age} years old`);
    this.setState({ submitted: true });
    e.preventDefault();
  }


  render() {
  // Here we're doing that destructuring again.
  // So, later on we can use e.g. 'name' inseatd of 'this.state.name'
  const { name, age, submitted } = this.state;
    return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:{' '}
                
          <input
               /* This the above used 'name' property -> e.target.name */
                  name='name' 
                  type="text"
                  /* Setting the current value from the current 
                  state value and making this into a controlled
                  form which is what we want 99% of the time */
                  value={this.state.name}
                  /* Here we are passing in a reference to our 
                  'handleChange' functions to the built-in 
                  'onChange' method */
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                  required /> 
                  

        </label>
        <br />
        <br />
        <label>
          Age:{' '}
          <input  name="age"
                  type="number" 
                  value={this.state.age}
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                  required />
        </label>
        <br />
        <br />

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
      <br />
      
    {/* Here will be our output. What we're doing here is checking if the FORM was submitted. 
//If that's true then we want to show our newly created string, but if not, we don't want to show anything in that case -> 'null' */}
      {submitted ? <p>{`Your name is ${name} and you are ${age} years old.`}</p> : null}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <FormComponent />,
  document.body
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What an amazingly helpful answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: Now to lead into my next question. - Is there a way to output the values to the page? 

What I am trying to do is take form values and use them as variables within a sentence that stays on the page after submit. 

I would love to hear your theories, facts, and opinion-based comments. - Do you see any issues with doing what I just described in a live environment?

Thank you once again!  :)

Comment: @Dr.Tenma YES, sure. I've just updated my answer. It's full of comments to get you started. I said I'll be here to assist, and I hope I was. Good luck with learning React. It's amazing. Don't get overwhelmed at the beginning, please. Once you get all the basics figured out, you'll be a lot more comfortable and happy you've stuck through. Cheers ;)

Comment: @Dr.Tenma You'll get there!

Comment: @BiggaHD One last question if you don't mind. - Do you think there is an advantage to using something like Formik for this?

Comment: It all depends on the size and complexity of your app. There are many things you can do with React without using 3rd party dependencies, especially since the `16.8` version. But, as your app grows so does the need for upgrading your stack. If you have a lot of states and need to pass props all over the place, then the `Context API` won't do the trick. So something like `Redux` is a must. The same goes for packages like `Formik`. If your `forms` get too complex, then an additional package is a good idea. Personally, I use `redux-form`. The short answer is: If you don't need it, don't include it

Comment: I will keep this in mind. Once again, thank you for your valuable insight.

Comment: @Dr.Tenma The right direction would be to post a question regarding your issue. I suggest making it fairly detailed with code snippet included, and also an error stack trace (if any is present). Cheers.